# Salesforce web service in java limiting results to 500 records

Tags: webservices, enterprise-wsdl

We're using the Enterprise web service to access SalesForce.  We built our enterprise.jar this way:

> java -classpath ./force-wsc-33.0.3.jar;./ST-4.0.8.jar;D:/apps/jdk7u25/lib/tools.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc U:\Projects\RemedyForce\prod_enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar

I see from this post [SOSL returning maximum of 500 records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23086/sosl-returning-maximum-of-500-records) 
that there was a problem with WSC version 23.0.  But we're using the newer 33.0 version.

We set up our configuration and Enterprise Connection this way:

```
// setup Web Service connection
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(USERNAME);
config.setPassword(PASSWORD);

connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
```

And then we call the service with our SOQL query string.

```
QueryResult queryResults = connection.query(soqlString);
```

`queryResults.getSize()` will often return a number larger than 500, but the actual list inside the object is always limited to 500.  Is there a way to either increase that limit or to page through the additional results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query results are broken up in to chunks once they reach a certain size, you need to use the queryMore call to fetch the next chunk. typically you end up with a loop like

```
  qr = sfdc.query(soql)
  while true {
    processChunk(qr)
    if qr.Done {
         break
    }
    qr = sfdc.queryMore(qr.queryLocator)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I also found this page to be helpful  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm